# Filling an array with a mathematical sequence

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write a code that asks for three numbers dig(1), dig(2), dig(3) and displays a sequence of numbers dig(1), dig(2), dig(3), ..., dig(n) according to this rule:

> - a = dig(2) - dig(1)
> - b = dig(3) - dig(2)
> - dig(n) = dig(n-1) + a if n is odd
> - dig(n) = dig(n-1) + b if n is even

Example:

> 7, 8, 5, 6, 3, 4, 1, 2, -1, 0

- It asks an user for three integers dig1, dig2, dig3
- It asks a number N ≥ 3 which will be the whole sequence count.
- It prints a sequence beginning with

Then prints the sequence, beginning with the three leading integers, followed by N-3 other terms that follow the pattern defined by the first three integers. See examples below for more information.

(The sequence begins with n = 1, but of course the array starts at 0.)

```
int dig1  = 0;
int dig2 = 0;
int dig3 = 0;
int a;
int b;
int n = 0;
int i;

dig1 = scnr.nextInt();
dig2 = scnr.nextInt();
dig3 = scnr.nextInt();
n = scnr.nextInt();

int[] array = new int[n]; 

array[0] = dig1;
array[1] = dig2;
array[2] = dig3;
a = dig2 - dig1;
b = dig3 - dig2;

for (i = 3; i < n; i++){
    if(i%2 == 0){
        array[i] = b + array[i-1]; 
    }
    else{
        array[i] = a + array[i-1];
    }
}
System.out.println(array[i]);

  }
}
```

whenever I try to print this out, I get this error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Another example: if I put in the numbers: `0 1 0 9` into my input, I should receive back the sequence `0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0`

Printing `array[n-1]` gives me back just the final output. I'm trying to iterate through each number.

Sorry if that's unclear, but any help would be great, thank you.

Comment: `n = scnr.nextInt();` ... what size of the array are you choosing?

Comment: You enter three elements to the array all the time. Try assign n = 3 and see if that helps. Also you should not really start by assigning i to 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `System.out.println(array[i]);` seems to be out of the for loop.  Then `i` will be equal to `n`. And there is no element with index `n` in array with length `n`. The elements are from `0` to `n-1`.

Answer (score 1):

At first I thought that you were choosing an array size less than 3, and that the code was failing here, during the initialization of the array:

```
array[0] = dig1;
array[1] = dig2;
array[2] = dig3;
```

But now, I actually think that the last line of code is the problem.  Have a closer look at your `for` loop:

```
for (i=3; i < n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        array[i] = b + array[i-1]; 
    }
    else {
        array[i] = a + array[i-1];
    }
}
System.out.println(array[i]);
```

Appreciate that at the end of the `for` loop, `i`, the loop counter, will always be `n`, the size of the array.  Accessing `array[n]` will always be out of bounds, because an array in Java has a highest addressable index of one *less* than the actual number of buckets.  So, if you were intending to just print the final element, then use this:

```
System.out.println(array[i-1]);
```

or

```
System.out.println(array[n-1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

at the line `n=scrn.nextInt()`, you are assigning to `n` a integer from `scrn` but you don't know the value of that integer.

Then with this:

```java
int[] array = new int[n];
```

Your array is of size of n elements starting from index **0** to index **n-1**.

So let's suppose the value you affected to **n** with `.nextInt()` is inferior to **3**: initial value of **i**, the loop will even not be reached, because you will be out of bounds just here:

`array[0] = dig1;
array[1] = dig2;
array[2] = dig3;`

since you will be attempting to affect a value on an array at an index that does not exists (**n** is inferior to three but you are trying to affect  three values in an array of size **n**).

Then if **n** is superior to **3**, since your **printing code** is out from the loop, the value of **i** is equal to **n** and there is no value at index **n**. remember, the loop will leave only if the condition `i<n` is false and to reach that condition **i** must be equal or superior and that will lead to an IndexOutOfBoundsException on printing.

I think you printing line code should be inside the `for` loop.